# Round date to arbitrary established start and end of the year in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm looking for **fast** solution to round date to the last day of the year, but the year starts in 1.10 and ends in 30.09. So, when I have 2020-04-05, it should round this date to 2020-09-30. When I have 2020-12-12, it should round this date to 2021-09-30. I have tried this function:

```
round_date_to_seasons <- function(dates) {
    rounded_dates <- structure(rep(NA_real_, length(dates)), class = "Date")
    for (i in seq.int(1, length.out = length(dates))) {
        if (month(dates[i]) %in% c(10, 11, 12)) {
            year(dates[i]) <- year(dates[i]) + 1
            month(dates[i]) <- 9
            day(dates[i]) <- 30
        } else {
            month(dates[i]) <- 9
            day(dates[i]) <- 30
        }
        rounded_dates[i] <- dates[i]
    }
    rounded_dates
}
```

But it's slow. If I made profilling correctly, slow is values assignment, so lines 7, 8, 9, 11, 12 and also 14 in the code above, but the last one is not so bad. I really need as fast as possible function, for vector of length 10 mln or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to do it step by step, you can use vectorized functions.

For example this will be a lot faster:

```
library(lubridate)
round_date_to_seasons_new <- function(dates)
{
  as.Date(ifelse(month(dates) %in% 10:12,
         as_date(ISOdate(year(dates) + 1, 9, 30)),
         as_date(ISOdate(year(dates), 10, 1))),
        origin = '1970-01-01')
}
```

I'm sure this can be improved some more, but when running it here, it's at least an order of magnitude faster.

Whenever possible, use vectorized functions in R.

In your example, in every iteration of the loop, the entire `rounded_dates`-object is retrieved (several times), one element is changed, and everything is written back to memory.
This is necessary if your function does something with the entire object. But in this case, the first iteration only looks at and changes the first elements, the second iteration only at the second, and so on.

If you use a vectorised function, R knows it should only look at one small part, and the results are only combined in the end.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
library(lubridate)
round_date_to_seasons <- function(dat){
    lubridate::ceiling_date(dat %m+% months(-9) + days(1),'year') %m+% months(9)-days(1)}

round_date_to_seasons(as.POSIXct('2020-04-05'))
[1] "2020-09-30 CEST"

round_date_to_seasons(as.POSIXct('2020-12-12'))
[1] "2021-09-30 CEST"
```